# PHP - Unable to connect to FTP - implicit SSL Port 990

Tags: php, ssl, ftp, implicit

I created a method which allows a user to export a database into a CSV and then upload it to an external FTP server.

I tested it on my local machine and everything seems to be working perfectly fine.

However once I pushed the code to the prod environment the connection seems to be timing out. I did increase the timeout on the server however that did not seem to help.

**I am getting the following error,**

```
There was an error in uploading the file :::: Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx port 990: Connection timed out
```

**code**

```
if ($fp = fopen($local, 'r')) {
        $ftp_server = 'ftps://' . $this->server . '/' . $remote;
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ftp_server);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 990);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->username . ':' . $this->password);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_ALL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $err = curl_error($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        if ($err) {
            mail(ERROR_EMAIL, 'ERROR - Uploading file failed!.', date('F j, Y, g:i a e O')."] - There was an error in uploading the file :::: " . $err);
            error_log("[".date('F j, Y, g:i a e O')."] - There was an error in uploading the file :::: " . $err . "\n", 3, __DIR__."/errors.log");
        }
        error_log("[".date('F j, Y, g:i a e O')."] - File Successfully Uploaded.\n", 3, __DIR__."/errors.log");
        return !$err;
    }
```

This is the contents of a function found within a class. Wondering if I am missing anything.

```
$remote -> this is the file path to the remote file. on the server. 

$local -> this is the file on the local server.
```

Comment: Could be a firewall issue. Have you allowed access to port 990?

Comment: thanks, I shall have a look into that. Hopefully thats the cause and everything works once thats configured.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with port 990 not be allowed. This was an issue with the Hosting provider so following up on another solution.

Thank you for the comment, saved me some time.